# Validate data inserted based on other data in the same table (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle-apex

I am doing a project in SQL Oracle and have found a problem, as far as I am quite new to SQL.

I have a system that administrates booked rooms, in a table called bookings. Some of the attributes are:

- room_id
- arrival_date
- nights_nr
- booking_id (which is the PK).

I have a UNIQUE(room_id, arrival_date) constraint.

To have a coherent DB I would need to check, for every inserted or updated row, whether any of the intended-to-book days for that room are already booked. This being a constraint based on the table's values, I would need a select so I cannot perform this in a CHECK (or at least I haven't figured out another possibility).

I am trying to do this with a trigger, but this is my first contact with triggers.

What I thought was to have a select in a when and to verify if, for another booking_id and the same room_id I am currently intending to update, the range of days I am intending to book intersects with the range booked.

Due to lack of knowledge I have written something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER validate_free_room
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF arrival_date, night_nr ON bookings
FOR each row
DECLARE a char(8)
DECLARE b char(3)
SET a=booking_id
SET b=room_id
WHEN EXISTS (
    SELECT booking_id
    FROM bookings r
    WHERE 
    (r.booking_id!=a 
     AND 
     ((arrival_date BETWEEN r.arrival_date AND r.arrival_date + nights_nr)
      OR
      (arrival_date + nights_nr BETWEEN r.arrival_date AND r.arrival_date + r.nights_nr)
      )
     AND
     b=r.room_id
    )
   )
BEGIN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20107,'Room already booked')
         end;
```

I have just found out that I cannot perform selects in a table that is being modified with a "for each row".

Do you have any ideas how I could do this in a correct way? (I know the precedent lines are a complete disaster).

I am using Oracle Application Express, which gave me the following error suggestions:

```
ORA-24344: success with compilation error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190200", line 592
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190200", line 578
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2057


3. for each row
4. declare a char(8)
5. declare b char(3)
6. set a=id_rezerva
7. set b=id_camera
```

and

```
Error computing plan for statement.
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

Comment: . . As a note:  Your overlap logic is not correct.  But the more important issue you are having is the mutating data trigger error.  You should be clear about the error you are getting.

Comment: This is quite tricky to work around.  I might suggest you start with a simpler problem, or do the check in the application (using a stored procedure), or use a different database.  Here is one discussion:  http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2016/12/get-rid-of-mutating-table-trigger.html.

Comment: Indeed, the mutating data gives me head aches. Thank you very much for the material! Unfortunately I am running out of time to use a different database. Oracle APEX does not really specify the error I am having, at least in a way I can read (in class I have seen that SQL developer is more specific). Again, thank you very very much for the material and the suggestions! (I am currently reading the blog post)

Comment: you'll need another condition to look for existing bookings that are entirely between your proposed dates. Also might be best to utilise a time component to your dates and have all arrivals commence at 1300h and departures occur at 1000h. If you just use dates/peg all your times to the same value then BETWEEN will prevent rooms being taken by guest 2 on the same day they are vacated by guest 1 (between is inclusive) but every hotel would want to support same day occupancy change of a room

Comment: If you really need to do it ion a trigger, then use a statement trigger , not a row trigger.  See [here](https://codingsight.com/oracle-as-workaround-of-mutating-tables/) for an example.

Comment: One approach might be to have the trigger populate a second table with a row for each day booked for the room. Then a unique constraint on that table would prevent overlaps. I haven’t tried this though.

Comment: By the way, in PL/SQL syntax `declare` marks the start of the declaration section which contains multiple declarations, not one per `declare`, the assignment operator is `:=` and each statement must be terminated with a semicolon. Also `char` is a fixed-length type which adds blank spaces up to the declared width. I suspect only a tiny percentage of developers who use it actually want that.

Comment: Also there is no `when exists` construct. I’m not sure what manual you are using, but the Oracle one is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/toc.htm).

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - I suspect OP meant `WHEN (EXISTS...`. The condition in the `WHEN` clause of a trigger has to be enclosed in parentheses, but other than that `EXISTS` is legal as the condition part of a `WHEN ()`, at least AFAIK. (...he said, surreptitiously adjusting his Nomex long-johns...) :-)

Comment: If the OP is new to triggers, I strongly suggest he read this: https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/the-trouble-with-triggers and https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2575882200346616184 and https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS01374

Comment: Wow! I never hoped for so many answers! Thank you very very much, I've learnt so many new things from your suggestions, corrections and comments! Thank you!

Comment: I corrected my answer below: the stats need to be gathered on the materialized view LOG when it has no rows, then those stats need to be locked. This is to work around a problem (at least in versions 12.2 and preceding, don't know about 18+) where the SQL to refresh the materialized view may include unfortunate hints.

Comment: The materialized view approach is interesting, I wouldn't have thought of that. But I think a stored procedure is potentially a better solution. It should be fairly easy to use the DBMS_LOCK package to serialize writes to the table to prevent anomalies between the time you run your select and the insert/update. You could probably even lock at the room level to allow more concurrent access via dbms_lock.allocate_unique. I'm not sure which approach would perform better in the long term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another way to do this that does not involve triggers:

- create a `materialized view` that joins the table on itself and contains rows only when there is an overlap.
- This materialized view should refresh on commit.
- It has a constraint `1=0` that will fail every time there is a row.
- So at every commit, if there is an overlap, the commit will fail and the materialized view will always be empty.

There are DBA-type things to be done so this will perform OK, such as gathering statistics **on the materialized view log when empty**, then locking thoses statistics.

```
SQL> create table bookings(
  2    booking_id integer primary key,
  3    room_id integer not null,
  4    arrival_date date not null check (arrival_date = trunc(arrival_date)),
  5    nights_nr integer not null,
  6    UNIQUE(room_id, arrival_date)
  7  );

Table BOOKINGS created.

SQL> create materialized view log on bookings with rowid including new values;

Materialized view log BOOKINGS created.

SQL> create materialized view bookings_conflicts
  2  refresh fast on commit as
  3  select a.rowid arid, b.rowid brid
  4  from bookings a, bookings b
  5  where a.room_id = b.room_id 
  6    and a.arrival_date < b.arrival_date
  7    and a.arrival_date + a.nights_nr > b.arrival_date;

Materialized view BOOKINGS_CONFLICTS created.

SQL> alter materialized view bookings_conflicts add constraint no_overlaps check(1=0) deferrable;

Materialized view BOOKINGS_CONFLICTS altered.

SQL> insert into bookings
  2  select 1, 1, date '2020-01-01', 5 from dual union all
  3  select 2, 1, date '2020-01-05', 1 from dual union all
  4  select 3, 1, date '2020-01-06', 1 from dual;

3 rows inserted.

SQL> commit;

Error starting at line : 24 in command -
commit
Error report -
ORA-12008: error in materialized view or zonemap refresh path
ORA-02290: check constraint (STEW.NO_OVERLAPS) violated
....
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Very useful!